# Using mail spool file for an entry in /etc/aliases gives errors in EL7

Tags: centos, rhel, postfix

For years (with EL6 and before), I have successfully used entries like this in my /etc/aliases file:

```
bugs:       /var/spool/mail/bugs
```

The idea being mail to a non-user can be shoved into a file for later processing, or archiving. When using RHEL7 or CentOS7, these entries give the following two errors.

First, without creating the bugs file, maillog error "cannot create file exclusively: Permission denied":

```
May 16 12:17:04 foobar postfix/local[17510]: 3D313673442: to=<bugs@foobar.org>, relay=local, delay=0.12, delays=0.08/0.02/0/0.02, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (cannot append message to file /var/spool/mail/bugs: cannot create file exclusively: Permission denied)
```

Second, If I pre-create a file with reasonable ownership + context:

```
ls -l /var/spool/mail/bugs
-rw-rw----. 1 postfix mail 0 May  7 19:34 /var/spool/mail/bugs
ls -Z /var/spool/mail/bugs
-rw-rw----. postfix mail system_u:object_r:mail_spool_t:s0 /var/spool/mail/bugs
```

I get "unable to create lock file" error

```
May 16 12:11:43 foobar postfix/local[17422]: warning: unable to create lock file /var/spool/mail/bugs.lock: Permission denied
```

I am able to get the messages delivered to files with the following ghastly permissions (1777 and 666), however this is obviously not acceptable for security reasons:

```
# ll -d /var/spool/mail; ll /var/spool/mail/bugs
drwxrwxrwt. 2 root mail 52 May 16 13:36 /var/spool/mail
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 postfix mail 6913 May 16 13:31 /var/spool/mail/bugs
```

EL7 is postfix-2.10'ish, EL6 that works is postfix-2.6'ish.

Comment: Is your mail dir sticky and permissive? (`chmod 1777 /var/spool/mail`)

Comment: No, but I made the change. In fact, I got it to "work" with 1777 on /var/spool/mail/ and 666 /var/spool/mail/bugs - this is obviously not acceptable as anyone can go digging into those files. Postfix is trying to act as some unknown user when delivering the message... but who?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this, without creating a new user, is to set in `main.cf` the parameter `default_privs = mail`.

Keep in mind that it is discouraged to use root or postfix for default_privs.